# Why is my inteliJ java eneterprise project looking different?

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, enterprise

Why I am not able to choose the application server and other stuff like how it is on second image?
I don't know why my java enterprise project looks different.

[This is how my java enterprise looks :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpYrO.png)

[This is how it should look, I think...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHxHd.png)

Comment: The one you are seeing is a newer UI, the second one looks like an older UI or possibly even the community edition.

Comment: You cannot make a java enterprise project in community version.

Comment: I'd say that's an older UI then.

Comment: check that you have all JavaEE plugins enabled.

Comment: @Popeye you were right! Thx man!